# Angle to point from a point that depends on the angle (2D)

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate my image so that the units gun points at the enemy, not the unit itself

[image: geometry]

I have A, B, and the length of the distance between A and C (xoffset in the pic). A and C are 2 points on a single image.

A is middle of the unit
C is basically his shoulder behind the gun
B is the center of the enemy unit

Anyway, I can't figure out how to find theta, I'd love some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following picture, your angle $\theta$ equals angle $a$, and $\angle CAB$ equals the sum of angles $a$ and $b$.

[image]

I hope I understand you correctly. It sounds like you have the coordinates for $A$ and $B$ and also the length $x$. Let's say we have $A=(x_a,y_a)$ and $B=(x_b,y_b)$.

Then,
\begin{eqnarray*}
h &=& \sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2} \\
\text{angle } b &=& \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x_b-x_a}{y_b-y_a} \right) \\
\text{angle } a+b &=& \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{h} \right). \\
&& \\
\therefore\quad \theta &=& a \\
&=& \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{h} \right) - b \\
&=& \cos^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{(x_b-x_a)^2 + (y_b-y_a)^2}} \right) - \tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{x_b-x_a}{y_b-y_a} \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Spot on - my geometry really is rusty to not realize that angle a = angle theta - thank you!

Comment: @paycheck87 Glad to help.